# What would cause fastcgi_finish_request to take several seconds to execute?

Tags: php, performance, fastcgi

I have run into a rather strange issue with a particular part of a large PHP application. The portion of the application in question loads data from MySQL (mostly integer data) and builds a JSON string which gets output to the browser. These requests were taking sevar seconds (8 - 10 seconds each) in Chrome's developer tools as well as via `curl`. However the PHP shutdown handler I had reported that the requests were executing in less than 1 second.

In order to debug I added a call to `fastcgi_finish_request()`, and suddenly my shutdown handler reported the same time as Chrome / curl.

With some debugging, I narrowed it down to a particular function. I created the following simple test case:

```
<?php

$start_time = DFStdLib::exec_time();
$product = new ApparelQuoteProduct(19);
$pmatrix = $product->productMatrix();

// This function call is the problem:
$ranges = $pmatrix->ranges();

$end_time = DFStdLib::exec_time();
$duration =  $end_time - $start_time;

echo "Output generation duration was: $duration sec";
fastcgi_finish_request();
$fastcgi_finish_request_duration =  DFStdLib::exec_time() - $end_time;
DFSkel::log(DFSkel::LOG_INFO,"Output generation duration was: $duration sec; fastcgi_finish_request Duration was: $fastcgi_finish_request_duration sec");
```

If I call `$pmatrix->ranges()` (which is a function that executes a number of calls to `mysql_query` to fetch data and build an in-memory PHP object structure from that data) then I get the output:

> Output generation duration was: 0.2563910484314 sec; fastcgi_finish_request Duration was: 7.3854329586029 sec

in my log file. Note that **the call to `$pmatrix->ranges()` does not take long at all**, yet somehow it causes the PHP FastCGI handler to take seven seconds to fihish the request. (This is true even if I don't call `fastcgi_finish_request` -- the browser takes 7-8 seconds to display the data either way)

If I comment out the call to `$pmatrix->ranges()` I get:

> Output generation duration was: 0.0016419887542725 sec; fastcgi_finish_request Duration was: 0.00035214424133301 sec

I can post the entire source for the `$pmatrix->ranges()` function, but it's very long. I'd like some advice on where to even start looking.

What is it about the PHP FastCGI request process which would even cause such behavior? Does it call destructor functions / garbage collection? Does it close open resources? How can I troubleshoot this further?

---

EDIT: Here's a larger source sample:

```
<?php

class ApparelQuote_ProductPricingMatrix_TestCase
{
    protected $myProductId;
    protected $myQuantityRanges;

    private $myProduct;
    protected $myColors;
    protected $mySizes;

    protected $myQuantityPricing;

    public function __construct($product)
    {
        $this->myProductId = intval($product);
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of all ranges for this matrix.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function ranges()
    {
        $this->myLoadPricing();
        return $this->myQuantityRanges;
    }

    protected function myLoadPricing($force=false)
    {
        if($force || !$this->myQuantityPricing)
        {
            $this->myColors = array();
            $this->mySizes = array();

            $priceRec_finder = new ApparelQuote_ProductPricingRecord();
            $priceRec_finder->_link = Module_ApparelQuote::dbLink();
            $found_recs = $priceRec_finder->find(_ALL,"`product_id`={$this->myProductId}","`qtyrange_id`,`color_id`");

            $qtyFinder = new ApparelQuote_ProductPricingQtyRange();
            $qtyFinder->_link = Module_ApparelQuote::dbLink();
            $this->myQuantityRanges = $qtyFinder->find(_ALL,"`product_id`=$this->myProductId");

            $this->myQuantityPricing = array();

            foreach ($found_recs as &$r)
            {
                if(false) $r = new ApparelQuote_ProductPricingRecord();

                if(!isset($this->myColors[$r->color_id]))
                    $this->myColors[$r->color_id] = true;

                if(!isset($this->mySizes[$r->size_id]))
                    $this->mySizes[$r->size_id] = true;

                if(!is_array($this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id]))
                    $this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id] = array();

                if(!is_array($this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id]))
                    $this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id] = array();

                $this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id][$r->size_id] = &$r;
            }

            $this->myColors = array_keys($this->myColors);
            $this->mySizes = array_keys($this->mySizes);
        }
    }
}

$start_time = DFStdLib::exec_time();
$pmatrix = new ApparelQuote_ProductPricingMatrix_TestCase(19);
$ranges = $pmatrix->ranges();
$end_time = DFStdLib::exec_time();
$duration =  $end_time - $start_time;

echo "Output generation duration was: $duration sec";
fastcgi_finish_request();
$fastcgi_finish_request_duration =  DFStdLib::exec_time() - $end_time;
DFSkel::log(DFSkel::LOG_INFO,"Output generation duration was: $duration sec; fastcgi_finish_request Duration was: $fastcgi_finish_request_duration sec");
```

Upon continued debugging I have narrowed down to the following lines from the above:

```
                if(!is_array($this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id]))
                    $this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id] = array();
```

These statements are building an in-memory array structure of all the data loaded from MySQL. If I comment these out, then  `fastcgi_finish_request` takes roughly 0.0001 seconds to run. If I do not comment them out, then `fastcgi_finish_request` takes 7+ seconds to run.

## It's actually the function call to `is_array` that's the issue here

Changing to:

```
                if(!isset($this->myQuantityPricing[$r->qtyrange_id][$r->color_id]))
```

Resolves the problem. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe posting source to something like pastebin is a good idea. I believe the problem can be spotted there.

Comment: Also try profiling separate parts of `$pmatrix->ranges()`.

Comment: Posted a larger source code sample. `pmatrix->ranges()` executes in <1 second.

Comment: [Documentation](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#fastcgi_finish_request.28.29) says that `fastcgi_finish_request()` can invoke executing shutdown function. Are there any registered?

Comment: I have two shutdown handlers and I will debug those further, but note that in the above, my log message executes before my shutdown handler (The shutdown handler also logs a message about execution time) so `fastcgi_finish_request` does not appear to be calling my shutdown handlers

Comment: You can also try debugging with xDebug. It can create whisper files which can be later seen with something like kcachegrind. You'll see exactly which function takes what time.

Comment: It's the function cal to `is_array` that's the issue. I'll come up with a small test case and revise my question.

Comment: The only guess is raising notice if you call `is_array()` using something undefined.